# Decorator to create @property getters for all my class _attributes Python3+

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I am writting a class using SQLAlchemy that represents an object. I want many of its members attribute (in fact all) started with `_` (underscore) to have a read-only @property. I don't want to write that code that many times. So I thought about a decorator to apply to my class to read all its attributes and create a `@property` for the ones that start with `_` with the name without the `_` underscore. Like `self._age` gets a `@property def age(self): return self._age`.

I am struggling a bit since I have forgotten a bit about decorators I got so far as writting the bellow code:

```
def make_readonly_properties(cls):
    for attr_name in dir(cls):
        if attr_name.startswith('_'):
            setattr(cls, attr_name[1:], property(getattr(cls, attr_name)))
    return cls
```

And this is a sample class to test the idea, not working so far.

```
@make_readonly_properties
class X:
    def __init__(self):
        self._age = 34
        self._address = 'Unknown street at City Z'
        self.dog_name = 'Saitama'
```

I just started to wonder if there is not a PEP for this? Could be useful for `__` two underscores too.

Comment: `if there is not a PEP for this` No, because leading underscores are just a convention, and different codebases might want different behaviour. What if someone wants a setter? What if someone wants to prefix the attribute differently? What if someone wants their property to do more than just return a value, e.g. make a log entry every time the property is accessed?

Comment: @dROOOze good reasons. Thanks

Comment: With regards to your attempt, the fundamental issue here is that *the class doesn't have any of those attributes*. It has an `__init__` method that creates *instance attributes*, but the only way to know that information is to either run the method, or to extract it from the code in the method (this would be very messy to begin with). The way the standard library handles something similar, e.g. `dataclasses.datclass`, is by relying on *type hints* as the way to specify attributes, but that also creates an `__init__` for you

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks. That makes sense since they are called `instance` attributes but... what if I move they up out of the init I start to get them from dir(X)... hum thinking here...

Comment: Yes, because those are class variables. But relying on `dir` is really not going to be the way to do this.

Comment: Yes just got it, they are shared between all instances of the class... yeah no way to go.

Comment: uow someone sent me this https://gist.github.com/eusoubrasileiro/32c891c81503e63a9facaf6f90e382f9 not as I expected but works...

Comment: I will try another approach creating a derived class based on the original class. And use `vars()` within the derived class's `__init__` method to access the instance attributes and maybe create the @property getters? Tomorrow I will continue. Thanks for all help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental issue here is that the class doesn't have any of those attributes. It has an `__init__` method that creates instance attributes, but the only way to know that information is to either run the method, or to extract it from the code in the method (this would be very messy to begin with). The way the standard library handles something similar, e.g. `dataclasses.datclass`, is by relying on type hints as the way to specify attributes, but that also creates an `__init__` for you. Frankly, I think that is the best approach.

But this is Python, and we can do a lot of introspection, so why don't we actually try and see how far we can get with the messier alternative. We can use `inspect` to extract the source code from the method. If it is in a class definition, it it will be indented, so we can use `textwrap.dedent` to make it parsable, because we are going to use the `ast` module to walk the abstract syntax tree, and check for any *assignments to an attribute*.

```
def make_readonly_properties(cls):
    import ast, inspect, textwrap
    __init__ = vars(cls)['__init__'] # ignoring inheritance here and assume that an `__init__` was written
    tree = ast.parse(textwrap.dedent(inspect.getsource(__init__)))
    attrs = set()
    for node in ast.walk(tree):
        if isinstance(node, ast.Assign):
            for target in node.targets:
                if isinstance(target, ast.Attribute):
                    attrs.add(target.attr)

    def getter_maker(attr_name):
        def _fget(self):
            return getattr(self, attr_name)
        return _fget

    for attr_name in attrs:
        if attr_name.startswith('_'):
            setattr(cls, attr_name[1:], property(fget=getter_maker(attr_name)))

    return cls

@make_readonly_properties
class X:
    def __init__(self):
        self._age = 34
        self._address = 'Unknown street at City Z'
        self.dog_name = 'Saitama'
```

Note, the above doesn't handle inheritance, and assumes an `__init__` was written in the class definition. And we can say that is on purpose for the sake of simplicity and sanity.

Here is a little test in an ipython REPL:

```
In [1]: def make_readonly_properties(cls):
   ...:     import ast, inspect, textwrap
   ...:     __init__ = vars(cls)['__init__'] # ignoring inheritance here and assume that an `__init__` was written
   ...:     tree = ast.parse(textwrap.dedent(inspect.getsource(__init__)))
   ...:     attrs = set()
   ...:     for node in ast.walk(tree):
   ...:         if isinstance(node, ast.Assign):
   ...:             for target in node.targets:
   ...:                 if isinstance(target, ast.Attribute):
   ...:                     attrs.add(target.attr)
   ...:
   ...:     def getter_maker(attr_name):
   ...:         def _fget(self):
   ...:             return getattr(self, attr_name)
   ...:         return _fget
   ...:
   ...:     for attr_name in attrs:
   ...:         if attr_name.startswith('_'):
   ...:             setattr(cls, attr_name[1:], property(fget=getter_maker(attr_name)))
   ...:
   ...:     return cls
   ...:
   ...: @make_readonly_properties
   ...: class X:
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         self._age = 34
   ...:         self._address = 'Unknown street at City Z'
   ...:         self.dog_name = 'Saitama'
   ...:

In [2]: x = X()

In [3]: x.age
Out[3]: 34

In [4]: x.address
Out[4]: 'Unknown street at City Z'

In [5]: x.dog_name
Out[5]: 'Saitama'

In [6]: x.age = 1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 1
----> 1 x.age = 1

AttributeError: property of 'X' object has no setter

In [7]: x.address = "foo"
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 1
----> 1 x.address = "foo"

AttributeError: property of 'X' object has no setter

In [8]: x.dog_name = "Fido"
```

Comment: Crazy bastard!! (that's an compliment :)  Inspect the code and extract assignments to an attribute... Uoww I didn't even know that existed....

Comment: @imbr thanks. It's just tricks I've picked up reading answers and questions on here. I would say, in a professional code base, I might err on the side of avoiding as much  of this type of magic as possible. But if the use-case is constrained enough, maybe it is usable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy with inheritance instead of a class decorator, here you have three slightly different solutions.

### Custom __getattr__ and __setattr__

```
class ReadOnlyMixin:
   def __getattr__(self, name):
        return super().__getattribute__("_" + name)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if "_" + name in self.__dict__:
            raise AttributeError("can't set attribute")
        super().__setattr__(name, value)
```

The `__getattr__` method is called if the default attribute access fails. In that case, the object tries to get the attribute again but this time using the private name.

An attribute is made read only by extending the `__setattr__` method. We simply raise an AttributeError if a private attribute with the same name exists.

Here's how it works:

```
class X(ReadOnlyMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        self._age = 34
        self._address = 'Unknown street at City Z'
        self.dog_name = 'Saitama'
```

```
>>> x = X()
>>> x._age
34
>>> x.age
34
>>> x.age = 33
AttributeError: cant set attribute
>>> # Create a new private attribute and related read-only property
>>> x._cat_name = "cato"
>>> x.cat_name
'cato'
```

Even though the behaviour is (probably almost) identical to setting the properties manually, there is a difference in implementation. Properties modify the `__get__` and `__set__` methods for that attribute.

### Using property

This solution is similar to one already proposed, but it has the advantage of using a mixin class instead of introspecting what happens in the init method. In my opinion this is clearer, and also allows to dynamically create new private attributes and their corresponding read-only property.

```
def _get_maker(name):
    def fget(self):
        return getattr(self, name)
    return fget
        
class ReadOnlyMixin:
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name.startswith("_") and name not in self.__dict__:
            setattr(self.__class__, name[1:], property(fget=_get_maker(name)))
        super().__setattr__(name, value)
```

### Using descriptors

Here's another solution that uses a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#descriptorhowto), ie any object that implements `__get__` or `__set__` methods. This is somewhat related to what happens under the hood when using properties.

```
class ReadOnly:
    def __init__(self, private_name):
        self.private_name = private_name
    
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        return getattr(obj, self.private_name)
    
    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        raise AttributeError("can't set attribute")
        
class ReadOnlyMixin:
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name.startswith("_") and name not in self.__dict__:
            setattr(self.__class__, name[1:], ReadOnly(name))
        super().__setattr__(name, value)
```

Comment: that's a lot teaching. Aewsome man I did not know this stuff. Altough I have 2 more options on the sleeve I will problably use your last one since I will not need to use inheritance. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No worries, if you seriously want to blow up your mind check out the [metaprogramming tutorial](http://www.dabeaz.com/py3meta/) by David Beazley. I'm curious about how you managed to avoid inheritance. Maybe you could post your own solution.

Comment: thanks @edd313 I am already taking a look cool stuff thanks again!